# Pytest blocks pyside code from execution

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, pytest

I have a main window with buttons, labels etc.

I have a sample script with test functions.

I have a pytest fixture to get current executed test function name.

**I want to print that current test function name to a label in the main window.**

---

This is my code to get test function name:

```
...
request.node.name
```

This is my code for setting label in pyside

```
label_curr_test_name.setText(...)
```

And all together my code looks like this:

> testcase.py

```
def test_1(update_test_status):
    assert True
def test_2(update_test_status):
    assert True
```

> conftest.py

```
import pytest
from testmain import MainWindow # my window with the label created with pyside

@pytest.fixture()
def update_test_status(request):
    # implemented as singleton
    main = MainWindow() 
    main.label_curr_test_name.setText(request.node.name)
```

This doesnt set the label at all. One more thing which is important to know: I have a button "Start" which starts the pytest when clicked like this:

> testmain.py

```
 full_path = file_path + directory + file_name + '.py'
 pytest.main(['-x', full_path])
```

And after that command any call to pyside to set a label fails whereas without pytest running it works.

Anyone can help? What is the issue or how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. The issue was that pyside run in 1 main thread. Any other process that runs at that moment will freeze pyside. So the solution was to seperate the call for pytest in a thread.